# Coffeescript multiline regex replace confusion

Tags: javascript, regex, coffeescript

I need to reorganize an archaic cvs database so that it can be imported into ecommerce software with the correct special field names.

Here is some code I was matching against.
[id,category,manufacturers,model]

```
"1","3","Samsung","Galaxy S III"
"2","3","HTC","One X"
```

My regex

```
".*?".*?".*?".*?(".*?")
```

I basically need to replace only the manufacturer with a slightly more complex object literal like

```
{manufacturers: 'Samsung'}
```

but I can't seem to figure out how to selectively replace the third match.
I know I can split the string and extract the data I need, but I don't know how to replace the match so that the output variable looks like:

```
"1","3",{manufacturers: 'Samsung'},"Galaxy S III"
"2","3",{manufacturers: 'HTC'},"One X"
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: What code have you tried to replace the match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match this:

```
"(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)"
```

Replace by this:

```
"$1","$2",{manufacturers: '$3'},"$4"
```

---

Example:

```
var s='"1","3","Samsung","Galaxy S III"';
var p='"(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)","(.*?)"';
var r='"$1","$2",{manufacturers: \'$3\'},"$4"';
console.log(s.replace(new RegExp(p,"g"),r));
```

Output:

```
"1","3",{manufacturers: 'Samsung'},"Galaxy S III"
```